# Polyglossia and biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, polyglossia

I am trying to typeset a document in British English, using XeLaTeX, Polyglossia and BibLaTeX, with APA-style references.

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra
```

Below is a minimal working example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
@online{test2012,
    author={John Doe},
    title={It is not working},
    date={2012-02-03},
    url={http://google.com/},
    urldate={2012-03-18}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\bibliography{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a reference. \cite{test2012}

\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

After appending the commands in [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16091/xelatex-and-apa), I get a different error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mkbibdateapalongmdy
```

The problem seems to be related to the question mentioned above, although British English is a common language, and the lbx files are present.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mimic BibTeX "apalike" with BibLaTeX - (biblatex-apa broken?)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48023/mimic-bibtex-apalike-with-biblatex-biblatex-apa-broken)

Comment: I looked at that question indeed, but it seems he is trying to replicate the APA-style without using biblatex-apa.

Comment: I replicated the apalike style without using biblatex-apa as I was not able to get it to work with polyglossia. I am quite surprised how "easy" it is given Ulrikes answer below. This is something the biblatex-apa package author should take into consideration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is not directly related to polyglossia. The problem is that that there is no `english-apa.lbx`. The existing `british-apa.lbx` defines extras for british. And as mentioned in the biblatex documentation "`\DeclareLanguageMapping` is not intended to handle language variants (e. g., American English vs. British English) or babel language aliases (e. g., USenglish vs. american)."

So this would break too:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{british-apa}
```

While this here works fine:

```
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
```

One solution is to make a copy of `british-apa.lbx` and to name it e.g. `english-apa.lbx` and to change at least the `british` after `\DefineBibliographyExtras` and in the `\ProvidesFile` to english. Then this here works:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
```

It is probably possible to write a shorter `lbx` which reuses most of the definitions of `british-apa.lbx`, but I don't know enough of biblatex to write this file directly.

Another solution of the problem could be to write a `gloss-british.ldf` for polyglossia.

Comment: Copying the british-apa.lbx did the trick for me, but XeLaTeX did not find it in the same directory as the other biblatex-apa lbx files. When I copied the file to the same directory as my tex file, it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: You probably didn't update the filename database correctly (texhash with texlive). But the directory of the other biblatex-apa.lbx files is not a good idea anyway. local files should go in local texmf trees.

Comment: Biblatex-apa now includes an english.lbx. Also, remember that biblatex doesn't really support polyglossia, only babel

Comment: @RuudvA Your comment from 2012 about copying it to the same directory as the tex file just ended hours of frustration in 2016 :) Thank you so much!