# Problem with \mkbibdateapalongextra of biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

`biblatex-apa` gives me this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra 
                              {labelyear}{labelmonth}{labelday}\iffieldu...
```

I'm using the default (english) language, and have done the:

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{norsk}{norsk-apa}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa}
```

thing.

Here's a short example:

```
\documentclass[english]{memoir}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{roffe}
\usepackage[backend=biber,date=short,maxcitenames=2,style=apa]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{norsk}{norsk-apa}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{Papers2.bib}
\addbibresource{R.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{R-base}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This one replicates the problem.

Comment: Without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) we can only guess. Did you put `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa}` after `babel` and `biblatex`? Do you load the language `english` or `american` in `babel`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question would require for a definite/specific answer a Minimal Working Example, or [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: I've tried to build an MWE, but, and here's the rub, none that replicates this error. Which is why I'm stymied.

Is there anything I should look for in the .log file?

Comment: @roffe Well, if you have no way of reproducing the error, it is quite hard to track down the problem. You could start off with the affected document and delete the unnecessary parts, thereby arriving at a MWE. Did you try deleting all the temporary files and recompile? Maybe an update can help.

Comment: (http://pastebin.com/gNDrMnMk) replicates the problem.

Comment: @roffe We don't have `roffe.sty` and can't guess what it contains.

Comment: Opps, sorry. 

Just remove it.

Remove the line with Papers2.bib as well.

R.bib can just contain (http://pastebin.com/XT5FMs53)

Comment: See also [this very similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48557). Although it seems aimed at `polyglossia` instead of `babel`, the accepted answer there addresses what @moewe mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: See also [problems using apa6e with biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Update

Starting from `biblatex` v3.8 (2017-11-04) and `biblatex-apa` v7.5 (2017-11-05) **an explicit `\DeclareLanguageMapping` is not needed any more**. The mapping is automatically done for you with `\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix{-apa}`.

Of course this can only work properly if `biblatex-apa` comes with an `.lbx` file for your language.

Update `biblatex`, Biber and `biblatex-apa` to their newest versions if you experience problems with an undefined `\mkbibdateapalongextra`. The old version of this answer is left below in case you are stuck with an old version of `biblatex` or `biblatex-apa`.

---

### Old answer

If you use `biblatex-apa` you will need a language mapping for each used language (at least the main language) to its `-apa` counterpart

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
```

if your document is `american`. See also [problems using apa6e with biblatex-apa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864).

This is pointed out in the [`biblatex-apa` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa.pdf), § 3

> Specify the style in the usual way when loading `biblatex`. If you are
>   using babel:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[american]{babel}
> \usepackage{csquotes}
> \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
> \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
> ```

Refer to section 3.2 *Localisation* for a few more hints.

That means for *each* language you load with `babel` or `polyglossia` (but there things are a bit more complicated), you will need a mapping.

You will also have to provide a language mapping if you don't load `babel` at all. In that case the default language is English and you need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}`.

---

Whenever you declare a language mapping, `biblatex` uses the new file (in our case `british-apa.lbx`) if need be, that is if the mapped language is requested (in our case `english`).

`british-apa.lbx` contains some additional "BibliographyExtras" declared by `\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}`. These extras are only available for the exact language they are specified for (here `british`).
So even though we have forced `biblatex` to load `british-apa.lbx` instead of `english.lbx` we cannot use the "BibliographyExtras" since our document requests them for `english` only, but they are only available for `british`.

The relevant part of the [documentation, § 4.11.8 Custom Localization Modules, p. 232](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) states:

> Note that `\DeclareLanguageMapping` is not intended to handle language
>   variants (e.g., AmericanEnglish vs. BritishEnglish) or `babel`
>   language aliases (e.g., `USenglish` vs. `american`). For example, `babel`
>   offers the `USenglish` option which is similar to `american`. Therefore,
>   `biblatex` ships with an `USenglish.lbx` file which simply inherits all
>   data from `american.lbx` (which in turn gets the ‘strings’ from `english.lbx`). In other words, the mapping of language variants and `babel`
>   language aliases happens on the file level, the point being that
>   `biblatex`'s language support can be extended simply by adding
>   additional `lbx` files.

The simplest solution would be to use `british` or `american` instead of the "generic" `english`.

The following MWE works on my machine.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,date=short,maxcitenames=2,style=apa]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Manual{R-base,
  title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
  author = {{R Development Core Team}},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  address = {Vienna, Austria},
  year = {2008},
  isbn  = {3-900051-07-0},
  url = {http://www.R-project.org},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \cite{R-base}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

If you do not want to switch to a language other than `english`, you can go with the fix suggested in [Polyglossia and biblatex-apa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48569/35864).

Copy `british-apa.lbx` to a place LaTeX can find it, rename it to `english-apa.lbx` and replace all occurrences of `british` with `english` (the most important of which is `\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}` which becomes `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}`)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message and the reason was simple – my language (Finnish) is not yet (today, 2021-12-12) included in the official LaTeX distribution:

https://www.tug.org/texlive//Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa6/

although someone has made the localization in Github:

https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/lbx/finnish-apa.lbx

I spotted the problem by looking carefully through the pdflatex output, there was a warning I missed first (lost in the jungle of Overfull hbox -warnings):

```
    Package biblatex Warning: File 'finnish-apa.lbx' not found!
(biblatex)                Ignoring mapping 'finnish' -> 'finnish-apa'.
```

The solution is either to install the Finnish-apa.lbx manually (see where your distribution stores the other lbx files) or using other citation style if possible (I chose "authordate", works like charm.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!