# Problem with apa style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I have a problem using `apa` style in BibLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{cmap}                   
\usepackage{mathtext}               
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibl1.bib}

\begin{document}

Text, text...
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra 
                                  {year}{month}{day}\iffieldundef {endyear}{...
```

I found solutions for other languages but TeXstudio doesn't recognize `\DeclareLanguageMapping` and I didn't find `russian-apa.lbx`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You might try to write it yourself. It is not that long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` defines some essential macros in the `.lbx` files, so for every language you use in your document you need

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{<lang>}{<lang>-apa}
```

> Starting from `biblatex` v3.8/`biblatex-apa` v7.5 there should be no need for manual `\DeclareLanguageMapping`s any more. `biblatex-apa` now automatically sets the mappings for all languages with `\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix{-apa}`. Of course this can only work if the file `<lang>-apa.lbx` is present.

Unfortunately, there is no `russian-apa.lbx` and so the line `\DeclareLanguageMapping{russian}{russian-apa}` won't really help, we only get a message that `rusian-apa.lbx` was not found and the mapping is ignored.

The best solution is to write `russian-apa.lbx`. You can take any of the `...-apa.lbx`s as starting point and translate the file. See [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864). Here this would probably involve copying `english-apa.lbx` to `russian-apa.lbx`, changing the date and ID at the top, translating the contents and modifying the date format to Russian usage.

---

For a quick fix you can simply add

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{russian}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#1}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldbibstring{#1}{\biblcstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\thefield{#1}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldundef{#1}%
        {}%
        {\addcomma\addspace}%
       \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}%
      {}%
      {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{#2}\OR\iffieldundef{#1}}%
        {}%
        {\addspace}%
       \stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalongextra#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#1}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldbibstring{#1}{\biblcstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\thefield{#1}}\printfield{extrayear}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldundef{#1}%
        {}%
        {\addcomma\addspace}%
       \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}%
      {}%
      {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{#2}\OR\iffieldundef{#1}}%
        {}%
        {\addspace}%
       \stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalongmdy#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#2}%
      {}%
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}%
      {}%
      {\addspace}%
       \stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}%
      {}%
      {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{#3}}%
        {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{#2}}%
          {}%
          {\addspace}}%
        {\addcomma\addspace}%
       \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\biblcstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\thefield{#1}}}}}
```

to your preamble. (Modify it to Russian customs if need be.)

Comment: See also [Problem with \mkbibdateapalongextra of biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133700/35864), [problems using apa6e with biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864).