# Can't define apa as bibstyle "Undefined control sequence. <argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra"

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I have to write a report using APA style bibliography, using this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
bibstyle=apa,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Doesn't end processing, the bibliography is never printed, instead:

```
Package biblatex Info: No input encoding detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'ascii'.
\openout3 = `test.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'test.bbl' found.
(./test.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 19.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 19.


LaTeX Warning: Citation '*' on page 1 undefined on input line 21.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra 
                                  {year}{month}{day}\iffieldundef {endyear}{...
l.24
```

is found in the log file. If I use `citestyle`, this error doesn't appear. `style` produces the same problem. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133982/33619) makes allusion that I need to define just one language in babel, but using `language=american` as recommended produce the same result.

Comment: See also [problems using apa6e with biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864). Where in the answer did you find the allusion that one may only load one language? In the example it was important that one could not alias `english` to `american-apa` with `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa}`. I have now added a short paragraph about the general problem to the answer. But please let me know what I can do to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having [re-read again the manual](http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa.pdf), I saw in the "Use" section:

> Specify the style in the usual way when loading BibLATEX. If you are using
>   babel:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[american]{babel}
> \usepackage{csquotes}
> \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
> \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
> ```

I wasn't using the `\DeclareLanguageMapping` command that matched my babel preferences. Using

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
sorting=none,
citestyle=numeric,
url=true,
backref=true,
bibstyle=apa
]
{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}
```

Fixed the issue. Must make sure that babel's and DeclareLanguageMapping languages matches, and that `<texmf>/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/<language>-apa.lbx` has the language present.

Comment: More recent versions of `biblatex-apa` apply `\DeclareLanguageMapping` automatically for all languages. So now the only bottleneck is whether or not `biblatex-apa` has a `<language>-apa.lbx` for your document language `<language>`.

Comment: @moewe that's super. Do you have in hand the specific commit/version for this change? I tried reading the RELEASE file, but I remember still needing it in late '17 on Debian testing, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: `biblatex-apa` v7.5 (2017-11-05) and `biblatex` 3.8 (2017-11-04).