# APA bibliography (yearmonthday)

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm trying to make an alphabetically ordered bibliography for my report. Currently I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin={2cm,2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}\
\usepackage[ backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=ynt ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{sample.bib}
    \DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}\
    \title{How do we know what the inner structure of planet Earth is like?}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \section{Introduction and Theoretical brackground} \cite{lehmann}
        \printbibliography
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

with my .bib file:

```
@article{lehmann,
  author =   {Lehmann, I.},
  title =    {P'},
  journal =  {Publications du Bureau Central Sismologique International, Série A, Travaux Scientifique, 14},
  year =     1936,
  pages =    {87-115}
}
```

When I compile, the reference shows:

> Lehmann, I. (yearmonthday). P'.Publications du Bu-
>   reau  Central  Sismologique  International,  Série
>   A, Travaux Scientifique, 14, 87-115.

How can I make it display just the year (1936), instead of (yearmonthday). I'm using the APA style because I want a comma between the author and the year in the references.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [problems using apa6e with biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36331/35864). You will need to load `babel` with your document language and give the correct `\DeclareLanguageMapping`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
```

(or whatever other language you want to declare)
as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133700/problem-with-mkbibdateapalongextra-of-biblatex-apa) it works for me.