# Failure to use APA bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am writing an essay using bibliography generated by biblatex. My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authortitle, style=apa]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Biblio2}

\begin{document}

Sample text\footcite{4Dintro, 4Dsee, MultiDimension}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

But when running biblatex using the `style=apa` option, it returns the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \datecircaprint \mkbibdateapalongextra 
                                              {labelyear}{labelmonth}{la...
```

How can I fix this? Here's my `Biblio2` file:

```
@online{4Dintro,
author={Jones, Garrett},
title={Introduction to the Fourth Dimension},
date={2003-12-23},
url={http://hi.gher.space/classic/introduction.htm},
urldate={2017-07-25},
}

@online{4Dsee,
author={Edmonds, Molly},
title={Can Our Brains See the Fourth Dimension?},
date={2010-05-18},
url={http://science.howstuffworks.com/science-vs-myth/everyday-myths/see-
the-fourth-dimension.htm},
urldate={2017-07-24},
}

@article{MultiDimension,
author={Randall, Lisa and Sundrum, Raman},
title={Focus: An Invisible Dimension},
journaltitle={Physics Review Focus},
date={1999-12-02},
volume={4},
number={28},
url={https://physics.aps.org/story/v4/st28},
urldate={2017-07-25},
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce you error. Just a couple of notes. You should use `\addbibresource{Biblio2.bib}` instead of `\bibliography{Biblio2}`. And in your example `citestyle=authortitle` has no effect because `style=apa` sets both `citestyle` and `bibstyle` to `apa`.

Comment: Look at [Problem with \mkbibdateapalongextra of biblatex-apa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133700/problem-with-mkbibdateapalongextra-of-biblatex-apa). Add `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}`.

Comment: moewe's answer to the earlier question works fine with current Biblatex & your code. (Use `american` if you want that rather than `british`.)