# How to mention where a citation is used in the references section?

Tags: biblatex

My question is rather the opposite, since I want to remove the **bolded** part from a citation:

Xu, J., Benbasat, I., & Cenfetelli, R. T. (labelyearlabelmonthlabelday). “Integrating service quality with sys-tem and information quality: An empirical test in the e-service context,”MIS quarterly, 777–794. **( )(cit. on p.6)**.

This is the cls code which came with the [template](https://github.com/rschuetzler/latex-icis-template/blob/master/biblatex.cfg), perhaps you could point to where that is coming from:

```
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

% Put titles in quotes for most types
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [online,article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,thesis,unpublished,patent]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\addcomma}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [book]
  {title}{\mkbibemph{#1\addcomma}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [inbook,incollection,inproceedings]
  {booktitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\addcomma}}

% Attempted Fixes for ONLINE entries
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  url = {available online at},
  }

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\printtext{accessed}\space#1}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
   \printfield{url}\addsemicolon\space
   \printurldate
  }}

% Year formatting
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
       \printfield{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}%
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \iffieldundef{month}
    {}
    {\printdate}}%
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{issue}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{month}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext{%
       \printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printdate}}%
  \newunit}

% Fix names
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addperiod\space }
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{,\addspace and\addspace }

% Fix "in"
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \printtext{%
    in\space}}

% Gotta get rid of the "in" before journal title
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% Make (Volume:Issue)
\newbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{:}%
  \printfield{number}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

% Fix editor
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{apaeditorstrg}{editor}}%
     % \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\newbibmacro*{apaeditorstrg}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{#1type}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{#1}>1\OR\ifandothers{#1}}
       {\bibstring{editors}}
       {\bibstring{editor}}}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{#1}>1\OR\ifandothers{#1}}
         {\bibcpstring{type\thefield{#1type}s}}
         {\bibcpstring{type\thefield{#1type}}}}}

% Fix appearance of , with name lists of two
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
\endinput
```

Comment: Could you please post a compilable [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) in order to illustrate your problem. Apart from that, you might want to have a look, if you load `biblatex` with the `backref` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling for the characteristic phrase

```
% Gotta get rid of the "in" before journal title
```

in the comments leads to https://github.com/rschuetzler/latex-icis-template/blob/master/biblatex.cfg and indeed the contents of that file are identical to the `.cfg` in your question.

If I run the `testdoc.tex` included in the repository in its current state I do not get the backref/pageref output

> (cit. on p. 1)

But there is a second characteristic bit in your question, the

> labelyearlabelmonthlabelday

suggests that you are using `biblatex-apa` and failed to provide an appropriate language mapping or definition (cf. [Problem with \mkbibdateapalongextra of biblatex-apa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133700/35864) and many other linked questions).

Indeed, if I change `icisfinal.cls` to load `style=apa` instead of `style=authoryear` I also get the

> (cit. on p. 1)

in the output.

`biblatex-apa` uses a slightly different way to control the back references, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/72. If you use `biblatex-apa`, the style automatically sets `backref=true` and lets you control the output of the backreferences with the option `apabackref`.

Unfortunately, due to the redefinition of the `@article` driver in `biblatex.cfg`, `apabackref=false` won't remove all backreferences with this template (the driver uses the standard macro `pageref` and not its `biblatex-apa` version `apa:pageref`). You can, however, still resort to the standard method of using

```
backref=false,
```

Add this line to the `biblatex` loading option and that should remove the unwanted backreferences.

I should add that it is always risky to deviate from a template (i.e. the change from `style=authoryear` to `style=apa`). If you don't have an extremely strong reason to use this template I would avoid it. In particular because the redefinition of the `@article` driver could have other unwanted consequences if you use `biblatex-apa`.

---

While I do enjoy a bit of sleuthing from time to time, please consider including all necessary/vital information (like which template you use, where it is available, ...) as well as a short example document that reproduces the undesired behaviour (a so-called MWE: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), or MWEB: [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)) in your question. That makes it much easier to answer.