# What is the default citation style in bibliography page?

Tags: bibliographies

As a starter, I am unfamiliar with the bibliography in latex. 
There are different citation styles like MLA, APA, CHICAGO. Which citation style is that in bibliography page among MLA, APA, CHICAGO? I cannot find this in google so very sorry to ask this simple question in this forum. Alos, how to switch to other styles (among MLA, APA, CHICAGO again) conveniently?

Comment: default for what? There are several ways for creating a bibliography. Most notably the old and a little rusty bibtex and the more modern biblatex.

Comment: The one using external bib file (not typing the style on my own). `\usepackage{biblatex}` and `\addbibresource{references.bib}`. In references.bib, I type the title, author, year, etc.

Comment: Than it's numeric. The references are numbered alphabetically by the authors. The labels look like this [1].

Comment: @kwy The default is a numerical style, also known as the vancouver system.

Comment: Numbered with Arabic numerals in the order of the authors last name.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the style appearing on the bibliography section. For example, title comes first, year at the end, author comes after title..... (MLA, APA, or CHICAGO)?

Comment: No. Usually, the author comes firdt, then the title. With biblatex documentation, you can see a number of examples, by category (numeric, author-year, author-title, alphabetic, and their variants).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using biblatex, the default style is `numeric`. 
This style creates labels with arabic numbers in brackets and the entries are
sorted by the author's last name.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
  @article{test1,
    author = {Jules Winnfield},
    title = {This is a tasty burger},
    journal = {Journal for american pop culture},
    year = {1994},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric, % default
  % style=alphabetic,
  % style=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

%%\section{numeric}
See \cite{test1}!
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## using the default, `numeric`

[image: numeric]

You can easily change the style with the `style` package option, all standard
styles are listed in chapter 3.3 of the biblatex documentation: type `$ texdoc biblatex` in your terminal.

## using  `style=alphabetic`:

[image: alphabetic]

## using `style=authoryear`

[image: authoryear]

## using `style=mla`

[image: mla]

## using `style=apa`

See this answer if you encounter a problem:[Polyglossia and biblatex-apa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48557/polyglossia-and-biblatex-apa/48569#48569)
[image: apa]

## using `style=chicago-authordate`

[image: chicago]

Comment: Thanks. `alphabetic` and `authoryear` produce different order in author names (first name and last name) and `authoryear` also include year immediately after author name. `numeric` has the same style as `alphabetic`. However, it seems that none of them comply with MLA, APA, CHICAGO style, where the first name is only indicated as Initial. Is there MLA, APA, CHICAGO style package in latex?

Comment: Yes, you can also specify `style=apa`, `style=mla` or `style=chicago-authordate`, there are several more chicago styles. See the documentation: on page 3: http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf

Comment: And there is a biblatex option `firstinits=true` which forces the abbreviation of the first name

Comment: I would recommend *not* loading `biblatex-chicago` unless you are using a Chicago style (it has two, the traditional `notes` specification and the `authordate` specification).  For most other styles, you load the "plain" `biblatex` packages, including for the APA and MLA styles.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using BibTeX, there is no default bibliography style. The bibliography style has to be specified explicitly with a `\bibliographystyle` directive.

Once chosen, the bibliography style generally also imposes a default style for citation call-outs. Some bibliography styles support only one call-out style (e.g., numeric in the case of the `plain` style), whereas others allow the use of more than one citation call-out style. E.g., `plainnat`, if used with the `natbib` package, supports numeric, author-year, and superscript-numbers call-out styles.

Typically, the journal or conference you're submitting a paper to will inform you which bibliography style, and which citation call-out style, should (or must) be selected. The beauty of BibTeX (and `biblatex`) is that it's generally a no-brainer to switch from one pre-defined bib style to another.